How to Call a FastAPI Endpoint on Google App Engine Protected by IAP as an End User?
I have a Python FastAPI application hosted on Google App Engine, and it's protected by Google Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP). I am trying to call the API as an end user (not using a service account). I understand that IAP requires an identity token to authenticate the user.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Generated an identity token using the following command:

gcloud auth print-identity-token

2.Passed the identity token in the Authorization header while making a POST request:
import requests

# API URL
url = "https://service-dot-project-id.el.r.appspot.com/endpoint"

# Generate identity token using gcloud
identity_token = "output_of_gcloud_auth_print_identity_token"

# Include the token in the Authorization header
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {identity_token}",
}

payload = {
    # Payload data
}

# Make the POST request
response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)

# Print the response
print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())


However, I get the following error:

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)


IMP: When I turn off IAP protection, the API works perfectly, and the response is returned as expected.

Question:
Is there a simple way to call an IAP-protected API directly from Python code as an end user (not as service account)?
Am I missing any step in the process of using the identity token?
I’m looking for an easy-to-follow method to handle this. Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Have you check what the response actually is, and not just that it isn't JSON? Have you checked the serverside log to see whether if the request hits your endpoint?
